# How to create a realtime chat using socket.io with using multiple servers (multiple ip)

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I have done to develope the socket.io realtime app. but this feature cant worked at loadbalance node installed servers like as diff ip.
this one is worked at only same server with same port only? here, data stored at server side like memcache & mongos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use redis as store with socket.io to load balance.

Basic demo here:

https://github.com/chirag04/socket.io-express-redis-demo